# How to remove last part of URL between last 2 slashes in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

How to remove last part of URL between last 2 slashes in google sheets?

EXAMPLE:
input : https://ssd@ssd.com:8443/job/OTHER/job/THS/job/TCC/job/title-title-NU2-ACP/job/title_T13-NU2-ACP/740/

output: https://ssd@ssd.com:8443/job/OTHER/job/THS/job/TCC/job/title-title-NU2-ACP/job/title_T13-NU2-ACP

i tried multiple formulas but didn't work

```
=Arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, ".*/(.*?)/$"),))
```

this returned 740 which is the part i need to exclude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Can you test:*

```js
=regexextract(A1,"(.*)/[^/]*/")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your formula

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,".*/(.*?)/$")
```

Would work if you entered the brackets at the beginning, like this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(.*)/.*?/$")
```

But we don't really need the lazy quantifier (?) and the end of string assertion ($), so it can be shortened to:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(.*)/.*/")
```